# jquery .show and .toggle open and close several times on one click

Tags: jquery

I want that my buttons (i generate many with asp.net within <% %> tags.) will show the "textboxHidden" div, and then Toggle the button value between "Respond" and "Close". and if I click the "close" button again, I want it to hide the div again...

in reality, when I click the button, it hide and show the div several times, and then hide the "close" button".
why is that ?

Thats the div:

```
<div id="buttons">
                        <span class="reply"></span><span class="reply">
                            <input type="button" id="replyButton<%=i %>" value="Respond" onclick="showTextArea('<%=i %>')" />
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="textboxHidden<%=i %>" style="display: none;">
                        <textarea style="width: 500px; height: 70px;" name="forum_topic_comment<%=i %>" id="forum_topic_comment<%=i %>"></textarea>
                        <div id="hiddenSave<%=i %>" style="display: none;">
                            <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="submitComment('<%=i %>');" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

thats the jquery code:

```
function showTextArea(i) {
                $("#replyButton" + i).click(function () {
                    $("#textboxHidden" + i).toggle(200);
                    $("#hiddenSave" + i).show(200);
                    $("#replyButton"+i).val('Close').toggle();

                });
            }
```

thanks for the helpers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `showTextArea()` should contain this only:

```
$("#textboxHidden" + i).toggle(200);
$("#hiddenSave" + i).show(200);
( $("#replyButton"+i).val() != 'Close' ? $("#replyButton"+i).val('Close') : $("#replyButton"+i).val('Respond') )
```

see : http://jsfiddle.net/hdfku/2/

Comment: Thanks! it works!.   but how can I make the "close" become "respond" again when its hidden again ?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, look what you are doing. You are assigning an onclick attribute on each button. On each click it will call the function showTextArea, where you add a new(!) click handler every time you click on the button. All of those click handlers will run on the next button click. With every click you get more click handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the onclick on the input and add a class "showTextArea" :

```
<input class="showTextArea" type="button" id="replyButton<%=i %>" value="Respond" />
```

And replace your js with that :

```
$(".showTextArea").click(function() {
    i = $(this).attr('id').replace("replyButton","")
    $("#textboxHidden" + i).toggle(200);
    $("#hiddenSave" + i).show(200);
    $("#replyButton"+i).val('Close').toggle();
})
```

Work fine for me

Comment: when I do that, it doesnt do anything when I click it .